# For the potential difference, how is it that $V=W/Q$=$U/Q$ when $U$ and $W$ are negatives of each other?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, work, potential-energy, conventions

I'm currently studying electric potential and am somewhat overwhelmed by all of the different equations and their iterations. For instance, the first definition I learned was that:
$$\Delta{V}=V_b-V_a=\frac{\Delta{U}}{Q}=\frac{U_b-U_a}{Q}$$
I.e. potential difference = change in potential / charge.

This made plenty of sense until I came across another version of this formula,

$$\Delta{V}=\frac{W}{Q}=\frac{-\Delta{U}}{Q}=\frac{U_a-U_b}{Q}$$

Here, $W$ represents work done. However, how can this equation be true when $W=-\Delta{U}$? Shouldn't the equation instead be the following?

$$\Delta{V}=\frac{-W}{Q}$$

Comment: ${}$ Seen where?

Comment: With all this work you must clearly define the symbols, eg $W$ is the work done by .........? $U$ is the potential **energy** of ..........? and also define the system under consideration so can clearly identify external and internal forces.

Answer (score 1):

> I.e. potential difference = change in potential / charge.

$\Delta V$ is the difference in potential (voltage) between points $a$ and $b$. $\Delta U$ is the change in *potential energy*, not the difference in *potential*.

Regarding the second equation, the first part of the equation

$$\Delta V=\frac{W}{Q}$$

comes from the definition of potential difference, or voltage $V$, which is: *The potential difference $V$ between two points is the work per unit charge required to move the charge between the points.* Usually there is no $\Delta$ in front of $V$, because $V$ is always understood to mean the potential difference between two points.

The equation

$$W=-\Delta U$$

means that the work done on the charge in moving the charge between two points is the negative of its change in potential energy. In the case of conservative forces, like electrical and gravitational forces, positive work is being done by the field.

For example, when a free positive charge is placed in an electric field, the charge will move naturally under the influence of the field. There will be a loss in potential energy making $\Delta U$ negative, as well as a negative change in electrical potential. The work done by the field is therefore positive (the direction of the force of the field being in the same direction as the movement of the charge). This is what happens when current flows through a resistor. There is a loss of potential energy and a drop in electrical potential across the resistor in the direction of current flow. The loss in potential energy equals the heat dissipated in the resistor. The gravity analogy is a free falling mass in the gravitational field after reaching its terminal velocity due to air friction. The subsequent loss of gravitational potential energy will equal the air friction heating.

On the other hand, if the positive charge is moved by an external agent against the direction of the force of the electric field, there is an increase in potential energy and electrical potential. There is positive work done by an external agent and an equal amount of negative work is done by the field (direction of the force of the field opposite to the direction of movement of charge). Since the net work is zero, there is no change in kinetic energy of the charge, only a change in potential energy. This is what happens when a battery delivers positive charge to the positively charged plate of a capacitor against the direction of the field in the capacitor. The battery is the external agent doing positive work on the charge equal to the negative work done by the electric field of the capacitor, resulting in an increase in the electrical potential energy stored in the capacitor. The gravity analogy is the increase in potential energy of a mass when the mass is raised at constant velocity by an external agent against the direction of the gravitational field.

Hope this helps.